# how to convert English numbers to Chinese in Java

Tags: java, android

I have to convert English number to Chinese numbers. But the Chinese number system is different than in English. Is there any way to convert english numbers at run time into chinese?

Comment: are you suggesting the english word 'one' to chinese character 'one' ?

Comment: ["Chinese numbers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals) is not exactly clear. China is huge if you did not know.

Comment: @Gary: I think it might be converting `1010` into `一千零一十`

Comment: Do you mean English word numbers (one, two, three) or Arabic numerals (1, 2, 3)?

Comment: @Gary Joey says right i wan't to convert Arabic numerals to chines number. example 1010 into 一千零一十.

Comment: @Vikram  i'll still suggest what i suggested previously.  A hashtable for look-up based on the wiki link i provided earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, 
i suggest you build a hash table for it. 
It's not that difficult to start with. 
we know that chinese 'numerals' are pretty much defined by:
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals

With that, i think you are more than capable to build a table in your programming lang preference, java.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rolling your own, it is advisable to use [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/) [NumberFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/NumberFormat.html) as @mcdowell's answer.

The only thing different is the Numbering Systems ID `"hansfin"` should be replace with `"hans"` if you wish converting `61305` into `"六万一千三百零五"`.

```
Locale chineseNumbers = new Locale("C@numbers=hans");
com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat formatter =
    com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(chineseNumbers);
System.out.println(formatter.format(61305));
```

Here is the results for different Numbering Systems IDes.

```
hans    六万一千三百零五
hant    六萬一千三百零五
hansfin 陆万壹仟叁佰零伍
hantfin 陸萬壹仟參佰零伍
```

The `hans` is the abbreviation of "Han Simplified" (i.e. Simplified Chinese), while the `hant` is "Han Traditional" (i.e. Traditional Chinese) and the `fin` is "Finance".

Answer (score 2):

[ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/) has support for this:

```
Locale chineseNumbers = new Locale("en_US@numbers=hansfin");
com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat formatter =
    com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(chineseNumbers);
System.out.println(formatter.format(100));
```

*Tested with version 4.8.*