# Get date in traditional chinese language in Android

Tags: android, chinese-locale, android-date

I am getting the date using the code below from a timestamp :

`java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(created_at) * 1000);`

I am currently getting the date in English but I want it in traditional Chinese language.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Might just need to convert the number.  See this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224177/how-to-convert-english-number-to-chinese-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Use Date Locale.

```
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG,Locale.CHINA).format(today).toUpperCase());
```